# How to use COUNTIFS when a part of text should be included and another part should be excluded?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently setting up a spreadsheet containing information on approx. `2,000` albums incl. rating, genre, year of release etc.

I now want to see the average rating per genre. For that purpose I'm using the following structure:

```
A1: Name of Genre
B1: =COUNTIF('Raw Data'!E:E; "*Emocore*")
C1: =SUMIF('Raw Data'!E:E;"*Emocore*"; 'Raw Data'!F:F)/B1
```

In my Raw Data sheet column E includes the genre of the album and column F includes the rating.

However, there are genre names that will pop up as a part in other genres as well. If I want the average rating for "`Emo`" for example, albums with genres such as `"Emocore", "Midwest Emo"` etc, will be counted as well since "`Emo`" is part of their genre description.

How can I exclude these to get a `pure` Emo rating, without counting `Emocore` etc. as well? Important note: an album can have more than one assigned genre, so a cell in `column E` can include more than one value (e.g. an album might be tagged "`Emocore, Hardcore`" in column E). That's why I'm working with *.

I was thinking about using '<>' but this doesn't seem to work for the rating part. `Column B` (number of albums per genre) works fine but for `column C` I'm getting a "#`VALUE`" error.

Could anyone help me out here? I'm struggling to fix it.

My non-working solution:

```
=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!E:E; "*Emo*"; 'Raw Data'!E:E; "<>*core*"; 'Raw Data'!F:F)/B1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use FILTER and REGEXMATCH in order to find these values. For example:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(E:E,REGEXMATCH(E:E,"\b(?i)"&B1&"\b")))
```

To the whole column or range of genres:

```
=BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(genre,
COUNTA(FILTER(E:E,REGEXMATCH(E:E,"\b(?i)"&genre&"\b")))))
```

[image]

You could apply the same criteria to get the sum too. But, in fact, you could just do the average with conditions in one cell with this same filter criteria:

[image]

```
=BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(genre,AVERAGE(FILTER(F2:F,REGEXMATCH(E2:E,"\b(?i)"&genre&"\b")))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This might be a stupid question but what is LAMBDA doing exactly? Right now I'm getting a formula parse error unfortunately. I've adapted the columns and cells in the formula to my spreadsheet of course:

    =BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(genre,
    COUNTA(FILTER('Raw Data'!E:E,REGEXMATCH('Raw Data'!E:E,"\b(?i)"&genre&"\b")))))